# Как присвоить родителю объект в Unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d

нужно присвоить `Main Camera` обратно родителю `Player`

вытащил камеру с помощью: 
`GameObject.Find("Main Camera").transform.parent = null;`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: GameObject.Find("Main Camera").transform.SetParent(GameObject.Find("Player"));

Comment: @Xumera_hZ, `error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'UnityEngine.Transform.SetParent(UnityEngine.Transform)' has some invalid arguments`

Comment: `GameObject.Find("Player")` подсвечивается красным

Comment: Ну так добавь .transform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если использовать ваш же код, то вот так:

```
GameObject.Find("Main Camera").transform.SetParent(GameObject.Find("Player").transform);
```

Но сам GameObject.Find желательно использовать, как можно реже. Лучше дайте скрипту прямые ссылки, либо, хотя бы, кешируйте (т.е. назначайте найденный файл в перменную, чтобы потом ещё раз не искать его через Find). т.е. выйдет что-то вроде этого:

```
var _camera = GameObject.Find("Main Camera");   
var _player = GameObject.Find("Player");   
_camera.transform.SetParet(null);
_camera.transform.SetParet(_player.transform);
```

Comment: а как можна напрямую обратиться, не используя `Find` ?

Comment: @KillNoise, ну, например, объявить переменную, сделать её публичной или добавить атрибут [SerializeField]. Когда вы выберете объект, на котором висит данный скрипт там появится поле, куда можно перетащить нужный вам объект. В дальнейшем можно в скрипте обращаться к этой переменной. Например, вам нужно работать с трансформом камеры и трансформом игрока. Создаёте две публичные переменные Transform. Выбираете объект со скриптом и перетаскиваете туда нужные объекты со сцены. Это, пожалуй, самый простейший вариант.

Comment: все понял, спасибо)
вашем коде неверно написан `SetParet` вы пропустили `n` нужно `SetParent`

Comment: @KillNoise, ну простым копированием чужих решений ничего не добиться - нужно самому искать, разбираться, да пробовать) а букву пропустил - т.к. не копировал, а просто набирал в редакторе тут) не слишком удобно. Если мой ответ помог решить вопрос - пометьте, как верный - тогда заходящие будут сразу видеть, что он решён и куда смотреть.